# AWS IAM policy to enforce new EBS volumes are encrypted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ebs

In the [AWS Key Management Service Best Practices whitepaper](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-kms-best-practices.pdf), in the section on Data at Rest Encryption with Amazon EBS, it states:

> There are two methods to ensure that EBS volumes are always encrypted.
>   You can verify that the encryption flag as part of the `CreateVolume`
>   context is set to “true” through an IAM policy. If the flag is not
>   “true” then the IAM policy can prevent an individual from creating the
>   EBS volume

How can I do this?  I'd imagine the policy would look something like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1509465260000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateVolume"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "ec2:Encrypted": "true"
        }
      },
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Based on the whitepaper and the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policy-structure.html#amazon-ec2-keys), the `Bool` condition on the `ec2:Encrypted` key makes the most sense, but when trying to create an encrypted volume, I'm getting access denied.

What am I missing in the statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need additional permissions to create encrypted volumes:

1) ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones

2) kms:*

Note: I did not drill down into KMS for the minimum permissions to use KMS encryption keys. If you want to create volumes from snapshots then you will need to add `ec2:DescribeSnapshots`.

Example policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1509465260000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateVolume"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "ec2:Encrypted": "true"
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had to add a few more Actions for my use case. Will post an answer showing exactly what I did

Comment: Thank you for posting the final solution. This will help others to better understand IAM policies. The principles of least privilege are very import with cloud security.

Comment: No problem! Are you aware of any good frameworks for IAM/KMS governance for organizations with multiple applications/development teams using the same AWS account?  It's easy to agree on 'principal of least privilege', but can be tough to implement and manage over time.

Comment: @tkwargs. Sorry I don't know of any better solutions from third parties. There are a lot of companies in this arena to review.

Comment: Are these Service Control Policies? It doesn't specify where these are applied.

Comment: @ScottCrooks - This is applied to the user's IAM policy. This policy gives the user permission to create a volume AND the condition that the volume must be encrypted.

Answer (score 4):

John Hanley had it right

The full policy I ended up using looked like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt2222222222222",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateVolume"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "ec2:Encrypted": "true"
        }
      },
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1111111111111",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
        "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
        "ec2:CreateTags",
        "kms:ListAliases"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "allowKmsKey",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:999999999999:alias/aws/ebs"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"kms:encrypt" alone doesn't work anymore for creating encrypted ebs. Found a working solution in the following links

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/key-policy-requirements-EBS-encryption.html

[Permissions for creating and attaching EBS Volume to an EC2Resource i AWS Data Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53190613/permissions-for-creating-and-attaching-ebs-volume-to-an-ec2resource-i-aws-data-p/53204613#53204613)

To use without doing a wildcard kms action ("kms":*), include the following under Action

```
"kms:Encrypt",
"kms:Decrypt",
"kms:ReEncrypt*",
"kms:GenerateDataKey*",
"kms:DescribeKey"
```

along with

```
"ec2:CreateVolume",
"ec2:CreateTags",
"ec2:DescribeVolumeAttribute",
"ec2:DescribeVolumeStatus",
"ec2:DescribeVolumes",
"ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
"ec2:EnableVolumeIO"
```